# Stochastic Optimization Techniques

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, stochastic-analysis

I am looking to collect stochastic optimization techniques
that would say under what conditions
\begin{align}
E[ f(X_2)] \le   E[ f(X_1)].
\end{align}
for some random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. 
Here is an example of one such result that  I am aware of

> If $X_1$ stochastically dominates $X_2$ and $f(x)$ is  non-decreasing then
>           \begin{align}
>     E[ f(X_2)] \le   E[ f(X_1)].
>     \end{align}
>       Where $X_1$ stochasticly dominates $X_2$ if $F_{X_1}(x) \le F_{X_2}(x)$ for all $x$.

The above is an example of first order stochastic dominance. There are other similar notions called second and third order  [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance).

This is tool can be very powerful in some stochastic optimization scenarios. However, it has its limitations. That is why I would like to collect of few other results that say under what conditions expectation with respect to distribution $X_1$ is larger (or smaller) than expectation with respect to $X_2$.

If anyone is aware of any other result with similar flavor or any good reference, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: This is true.   Note that if $X_2 \underset{st}{\leq} X_1$ then there is a random variable $Y$ such that $X_2 \underset{st}{=} Y\leq X_1$.  So if $f(x)$ is a nondecreasing function then $f(Y)\leq f(X_1)$ and so $E[f(Y)]\leq E[f(X_1)]$. But $E[f(Y)]=E[f(X_2)]$ because $Y$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Dear @Michael, perhaps the wording in my question was misleading. I am already aware of  this result and I looking for results of similar nature.  I have changed the wording of may question.

Comment: I see.  Well, you do not need the "piecewise differentiable" assumption for that result (as shown in my prior comment), and "increasing" can be generalized to "nondecreasing."

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function.  Let $\vec{X}_1$ and $\vec{X}_2$ be random vectors with the same mean, so that $E[\vec{X}_1]=E[\vec{X}_2]=\vec{m}$ for some vector $\vec{m} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Further suppose $\vec{X}_2$ has the same distribution as $\vec{m} + \theta(\vec{X}_1-\vec{m})$ for some constant $\theta \in [0,1]$. So $\vec{X}_2$ has a distribution that is scaled to make it more tightly concentrated about the mean. Then:

$$E[f(\vec{X}_2)] \leq E[f(\vec{X}_1)] $$

This can be viewed as a generalization of Jensen's inequality (the case $\theta=0$ is exactly Jensen's inequality and gives $f(\vec{m}) \leq E[f(\vec{X}_1)]$).

Proof: 
\begin{align} 
E[f(\vec{X}_2)] &= E[f(\vec{m} + \theta(\vec{X}_1-\vec{m}))]\\
&=E[f((1-\theta)\vec{m} + \theta \vec{X}_1)] \\
&\leq E[(1-\theta) f(\vec{m}) + \theta f(\vec{X}_1)] \quad \mbox{[since $f$ is convex]}\\
&= (1-\theta)f(E[\vec{X}_1]) + \theta E[f(\vec{X}_1)]\\
&\leq (1-\theta)E[f(\vec{X}_1)] + \theta E[f(\vec{X}_1)] \quad \mbox{[by Jensen's inequality]}\\
&= E[f(\vec{X}_1)]
\end{align} 
$\Box$

Comment: thanks. This exactly the type of result I was looking for. Let me know if you know a few more.